# Passing Data In an Array From One Class to Another One

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

An error in my code is preventing it from displaying the following output:

> BMW Buick Audi VW Chevrolet Ford Opel Renault Peugeot Citroen Mustang Mercedes Fiat

And then the same list but sorted in alphabetical order. This is a small code with 3 classes.
Please copy and paste the code to see for yourself.

```
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Data implements List<String> {


public static String[] brands = { "BMW","Buick", "Audi", "VW","Chevrolet", "Ford", "Opel",
    "Renault", "Peugeot", "Citroen","Mustang", "Mercedes", "Fiat" };

public Data() {
}


}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Brands {


    List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Brands(){
        this(null);
    }

    public Brands(Data data){
        this.brands = data;
        }


    public List<String> sortList(){
        Collections.sort(brands);   
    return brands;

}

    public List<String> reverseTheOrder(){
        Collections.reverse(brands);    
        return brands;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return ""+brands+""+sortList();

    }

}

public class Brandstester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data data = new Data();
        Brands brands = new Brands(data);
        System.out.println(brands);
        brands.sortList();
        System.out.println(brands);
        brands.reverseTheOrder();
        System.out.println(brands);

    }

}
```

Comment: `implements` means that you should implement it really.

Comment: Yeah, i tried to implement with all the imported overrided methods but the output is still giving a bunch of errors.

Comment: Make your Data class as an extension of ArrayList class.

Comment: Ok, after extending ArrayList it doenst give any errors but instead i'm getting 3 lines (in the console) displaying my package name (3 times). This is the output : packagename.Brands@13c5982 –